# Oracle, execute select * and select count from huge transactional table to tally count of select * from table

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]I have a huge oracle transactional table where I extract data at 4 hour intervals. I have a requirement to validate the count of this extracted data using a followup select count(*) from table query. However, both the
`select * from table where tend between sysdate-4hours and sysdate`
and `select count(*) from table where tend between sysdate-4hours and sysdate`
queries are required to start at the same time, as if they're running in a race.

The objective is to tally the count, and this table receives sizeable no. of transactions at the minute level.
I am adding the parallel hint for the select * query, it's giving good results, however when I am kicking off both the jobs, the extraction finishes long before even though the count query is running exceptionally longer.
how to proceed?

Comment: `code  SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(SHIFTASSIGNMNT, 2, 1) */ TO_CHAR(COUNT(1)) AS TOTAL_ROWS 
   FROM SHIFTASSIGNMNT 
  WHERE ENTEREDONDTM BETWEEN TO_DATE('2023-01-27 05:15:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2023-01-27 09:15:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
     OR SHIFTASSIGNID IN ( SELECT SHIFTASSIGNID 
                             FROM SHFTASGNMNTTRC 
                            WHERE ENTEREDONDTM BETWEEN TO_DATE('2023-01-27 05:15:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2023-01-27 09:15:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                         )`

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Does the `select *` query return a number of rows different from what `select count(*)` gets? Or is the issue that the parallalized query runs (unsurprisingly) faster than the non-parallalized query? Or what else?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you got all the concerns right. 1. I am tracking both the count(*) and select(*) for the ETL solution, as this is a highly transactional system, the accuracy of the ETL job is going to be under the scanner. Hence, apart from Job metadata, I have also added this auditable step. Yes, the parallelized query runs faster than the non-parallel. The actual problem is that the count query isn't completing even though both the select and count queries are kicked off the same instant and the select (Parallel) ends within time.

Comment: You have about the same query twice. Once you select the rows, once the row count. With the parallel hint you tell the DBMS to speed up one of the queries. So, why are you surprised that one query runs a lot faster than the other? That makes no sense. Either speed up both queries or none. If you speed only one up, it becomes faster while the other runs slow.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am totally aware that one runs faster and the other runs slower, it's configured that way. But my concern is that the count query, which does not have the parallel hint, is taking 5 to 6 hours, and timing out. Actually, it isn't supposed to take that long, standalone execution of the query concludes in 30 to 45 minutes to grab the followup count. I am wondering if something is blocking the query, as it's powered by AWS GLUE (Spark sessions) in my framework. This is undesirable as it would stall the program. Contd in next comment.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am not sure why is that the same queries when executed independently in a standard client like SQL Developer or DBeaver, executes fine and within my cut off time limits, but when the same is executed via GLUE, the count job stalls & takes unnaturally 5 to 8 hours before timing out or me killing it. Without parallel, the workload pulls 5 to 8 million records as count within 30 to 45 mins. This is what I desire. I debugged the query outputted by GLUE, both the queries are identical, not sure what's stalling it. Also, in another lower environment, the GLUE Job runs totally fine

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot help here. You are right, counting shouldn't take that much time. I don't know how big your table is. You say it's huge, so I assume we are not merely talking of a billion rows, but a lot more. Still, how long can it take to read a table sequentially and count its rows? I suppose that such a huge table is partitioned, and as you are accessing it by timestamps only, I further assume that it is partitioned by date or the like, which should help a lot with the query.

Comment: From the query you posted I see that you are only using a parallel factor of 2, so my first idea that that paralleled process eats all your CPU power doesn't seem to apply either. Maybe it's really some hardware defect we are seeing here? I don't understand the query by the way, for from the names it looks like a column called SHIFTASSIGNID should be the unique ID of the table called SHIFTASSIGNMNT, but then the subquery would be completely redundant. So maybe you can remove it to get the query run faster. But well, maybe it is just a misnomer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner exactly yes, the Degree of Parallelism = 2 is not going to use up all the CPU that's why it was put up. Actually, it's a transactional system so we're very careful about mounting heavy SQL queries else we could have used PARALLEL in both the SQLs. We're totally okay if the count job takes an hour, the only requirement here is that the SQL completes while it in reality takes 5 to 8 hours for unexplainable reasons. Alternately, I wrote a small java prog and kicked off both simultaneously, and they both concluded. I am literally banging my head against the wall now.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks as if you're bothered by question *what time is "right now"?* because two queries, ran at different times, have different sense of "right now".

So, how about setting it explicitly? Something like this:

```
declare
  l_now date := sysdate;
begin
  -- extract data, e.g.
  insert into another_table (col1, ool2, ...)
  select col1, col2, ...
  from huge_table
  where date_column between l_now - interval '4' hour and l_now;
  
  -- you want to know number of rows? Easy-peasy
  l_cnt := sql%rowcount;
  
  -- you want to count rows explicitly? OK, if you must
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
  from huge_table
  where date_column between l_now - interval '4' hour and l_now;
end;
```

Comment: no, it's not about the sense of now. It's about kicking off two queries: the actual query, and it's count query equivalent by dynamically substituting the TSTART and TEND date parameters supplied by the control table by adding 4 hours interval.

Comment: I am pasting the query below. My code is kicking off both the queries in the same time, like a race, that is get the data, also get the count. This is a secondary validation step, as we're building custom ETL solutions, where a DQC is required. We've already explored DMS, which is perhaps the best solution, however, we'd not be able to deploy DMS atleast in the next 8 months due to operational reasons.  Since both the queries kick off at the same time, I don't want either of them to be blocked, which unfortunately seems to happen. But then again, by theory, SELECT queries shouldn't block.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an offset from SYSDATE. Instead, store the last retrieved date_column value on the client side (or, if you prefer, in a control table somewhere) and on the next refresh start with that value, pulling all rows `>=`

(for dates with 1 second granularity, make sure to use `>=` and not just `>` )

This way your queries are consistent and it doesn't matter whether they run at exactly the same time.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same, the SYSDATE is dynamically replaced by adding 4 hours for subsequent runs, such that TNEXT = TPREV + 4 Hours, this is stored in the control table to capture each scheduled run parameters. Furthermore, the query is dynamically substituted for these values.